# Draw vertical lines in chart for a list of dates

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I get this error: "line 14: Cannot call 'timestamp' with argument 'dateString'='call 'array.get' (series string)'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected;
line 14: Variable 'lineDate' is not found in scope '#global_#0_#0', cannot register side effect"

for this script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mein Skript", overlay=true)

var dates = array.new_string(2)
array.set(dates, 0, '11 Jul 2022 12:00')
array.set(dates, 1, '13 Jul 2022 12:00')


i = 0
while i < array.size(dates)
    var lineDate = input.time(timestamp(array.get(dates, i)), title="Line Location")
    i += 1
    if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
        line.new(x1=lineDate, y1=high, x2=lineDate, y2=low, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, width=2, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

How can I fix or workaround that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert dynamic string to timestamp in pinescript. You will have to convert it where you have hardcoded the date. Then save in an integer array and plot it. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mein Skript", overlay=true,max_lines_count=500)

var dates = array.new<int>(2)
array.set(dates, 0, timestamp('11 Jul 2022 12:00'))
array.set(dates, 1, timestamp('13 Jul 2022 12:00'))


i = 0
if barstate.islast
    while i < array.size(dates)
        lineDate = (array.get(dates, i))
        i += 1
        line.new(x1=lineDate, y1=high, x2=lineDate, y2=low, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, width=2, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```